# WPF DataGrid calculated Total column

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, editing

I got a DataGrid to enter items /price/Quantity for a sale screen and I need a subTotal column ,  Price * Quantity,  and I don't know how to calculate the subTotal column when the user leaves the Price or Quantity column. this is my xaml

### Heading

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Datos,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Dato,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{ Binding Path=Descripcion}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{ Binding Path=Precio,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{ Binding Path=Cant,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total" Binding="{ Binding Path=Total,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and my ViewModel is like this:

```
 public class VM : VMBase
    {
        public VM()
        {

            Datos.Add(new CDato() { Descripcion = "item 1", Precio = 2.5m, Cant = 3m, Total = 7.5m });
            Datos.Add(new CDato() { Descripcion = "item 2", Precio = 5m, Cant = 2m, Total = 10m });
        }

        private ObservableCollection<CDato> _datos;

        public ObservableCollection<CDato> Datos
        {
            get
            {
                if (_datos == null)
                    _datos = new ObservableCollection<CDato>();
                return _datos;
            }
            set
            {
                _datos = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public void Calcular()
        {
            if (Dato != null)
            {
                Dato.Total = Dato.Precio * Dato.Cant;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Dato");
                RaisePropertyChanged("Datos");
            }
        }
        private CDato dato;

        public CDato Dato
        {
            get { return dato; }
            set
            {
                dato = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public class CDato
    {
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public decimal Precio { get; set; }
        public decimal Cant { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }

    }
```

When a user change the cell "Precio" (Price)  or "Cant" (Quantity)  The "Total" column must be calculated with this formula Tota = Precio * Cant

I can't find samples about this.

Can you help me with this?

thaks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create this by adding `RaisePropertyChanged( "Total" )` to the props, what is used for calculate `Total` property. I've created some example to explain how to.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Binding="{Binding Price, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Binding="{Binding Total}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And the viewModel props.

```
private int _price;
public int Price
{
    get { return _price; }
    set { _price = value; RaisePropertyChanged( "Price" ); RaisePropertyChanged( "Total" ); }
}

public int Total
{
    get { return _price * 2; }
}
```

**Update** 
According to the comment. It's necessary to implement `NotifyPropertyChanged` for the `CDato` class (or derive it from `VMBase`) and add `RaisePropertyChanged` for it's props.

Comment: Despite being obvious to users with some experience with WPF, I think it would be useful to mention that `CDato` class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (and define `RaisePropertyChanged(string)` method) in order for this solution to work. Perhaps it would be optimal if the `CDato` class derived from `VMBase`. I'm not picking on you or anything, I just think the less implicit assumptions the better the answer.

Comment: Hi, 
What are you saying is done the class "VMBase" implements INotifyPropertyChanged, as you can see in the propertys there is a call to `RaisePropertyChanged();` the VMBase class is this:

    `public class VMBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;   
    }`

Comment: Yes you're right, so you can write `public class CDato : VMBase` and add `RaisePropertyChanged` for it's props.

Comment: but CDato is a POCO class, just plain data, the VM is the one who implements the  `INotifyPropertyChanged `  there is the ObservablCollection of CDato objects wich is bind to the datagrid. My problem is how to update of the Total column when the price or Quantity changes 
thanks for your time

Comment: But you using it's data in the `DataGrid` and bind it to columns so I think you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and you want update `Total` column whenever count or price is changed, it's the simpiest way to achive the goal. And `CDato` is the part of `ViewModel`

Comment: Aaaahhh!!!!!  THANKS A LOT it works perfect!!! I do implement NotifyPropertyChange in the POCO Class (CDato) and do the calculation of Total Cell  in the propertys Price and Quantity and works !!! 
thanks again!!